# Jquery to sort drop down list in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

How can I sort the drop down list below? I need to sort it by name as well as remove certain options say the ones beginning with 'S'.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="bold"><a href="/admin/programs/" target="_top">Program Link</a></td>
    <td>
        <select name="ProgramLink">
            <option value="0">None Selected</option>
            <option value="2985">Cluster</option>
            <option value="2986">Seminar</option>
            <option value="2991">Services</option>
            <option value="2982">Biliteracy</option>
            <option value="2983">Learner MEC</option>
            <option value="2987">Day Class</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code plus adding `order` class to your select may help:

```
$('select.order').each(function() {
    var options = [];
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('S') != 0) {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), label: $(this).text()});
        };
    })
    if (options.length > 0) {
        options = options.sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a['label']; var y = b['label'];
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });
        var options_html = '';
        $.each(options, function(i, option) {
            options_html += '<option value="'+option.value+'">'+option.label+'</option>';
        });
        $(this).html(options_html);
    };
})
```

Note: your html code lacks the `</select>` ;)

Comment: Thanks! I am testing in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kaur/o6kwfze4/1/ somehow it is not working for me.

Comment: I'm sorry @Kaur, I've posted a test instead of the final version of it. I've edited the answer, now it should work, but **don't forget to add `order` class to the `select`** ok? ;)

Comment: I've updated the js code to the edited version of the answer and added the class to `<select>` and it seems work: https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_elia/o6kwfze4/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = $('select option');
options.detach().sort(function(a,b) {
    var at = $(a).text();
    var bt = $(b).text();
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
});
options.appendTo('select');
```

Comment: Add some description to your code, what it does and why will it work (with a fiddle or a snippet).